# Task Scheduler runs a missed task unexpectedly on a computer that is running Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler, debug, task-scheduler

Here is my case:

i have set a Task to Disable Network adapter at 8:00:00 pm and Enable Network adapter at 8:00:15. It works like charm but if the laptop is turned off and i turn it on at 8:30 then both tasks execute simultaneously and my adapter remains disabled. I have unchecked "Run task as soon as possible..." and trigger is:
On a schedule - Daily - Recur every 1 day - Repeat every 4 hours Indefinitely.

Has anyone come up with a solution to this behavior in Windows 10 Task Scheduler?

I see that Microsoft admitted this is a system bug and had a hotfix for Windows 7 but it looks they are not able to provide one for Windows 10.

Here is the link to the discontinued fix for Windows 7:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2698800/task-scheduler-runs-a-missed-task-unexpectedly-on-a-computer-that-is-r

Comment: Use one task. `cmd /c sc stop drivername & timeout /t 15 & sc start drivername`.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just making this an actual answer, Mark has the right idea. A valid workaround is to use one command for the whole thing, avoiding the scheduler bug.

`cmd /c sc stop drivername & timeout /t 15 & sc start drivername`

Comment: Just to clarify the command that best worked for me is: 

`@ECHO OFF
netsh interface set interface "Wi-Fi" admin=disable & timeout /t 5 & netsh interface set interface "Wi-Fi" admin=enable`